# Spring singleton @autowired service and shared state

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I have a controller and a filter in which I inject a particular service. 
<s>In that service I have a Hashmap   where I try to store certain information. The issue that I am running into is that although it appears that that a single instance of that service is created and injected into my controller and my filter it seems that there an two instances of the Map. I'm at a loss as to why. No matter how I tried to instantiate the map (or inject it) the behavior is still the same.</s>

It turns out the issue is that two instances of the service are created and injected one in the controller and one in the filter. It's not clear to me why this is happening and how to resolve it.

Following is an extract of the code:

```
@Controller
public MyController {



  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;


  someEndpoint() {
    ....
    myService.putData(key, value);
    .....
  }


}


public class MyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {


  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;


  public void doFilter(...) {

     //this is where I have a problem. 
     // the reference myService.myMap seems to be pointing to a different instance 
     // than the service.myMap in the controller which doesn't make any sense to me
     // the filter obviously intercepts all requests so I would expect that after that particular
     // endpoint is accessed the data will be there for subsequent requests
     myService.getData(..);

  }

  .....
}


@Service
public class MyService {


  private Map <String,String> myMap = new HashMap <String,String> ();


  public String getData(String key) {
    return myMap.get(key);
  }

  public void putData(String key, String value){
     myMap.put(key,value);
  }


}
```

Here is an extract of the app-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myPackage"/>
    <context:annotation-config />


     .......

    <security:http
    ........
    ........
    <security:custom-filter ref="myFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    ....


    ...........

    <bean class="com.mycompany.filters.MyFilter" id="myFilter"/>
```

and the web.xml

```html
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservice/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many context do you have? Can you post your web.xml? And also the context configuration?

Answer (score 2):

In your web.xml you set:

```
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

which creates one web application context initiated by your servlet.

Then you also have:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

which also creates a parent root web application context, in your case a duplicate one.
This scheme, properly used, favors the cases where you may have more servlets, each one defining its own isolated context but inherit bean definitions from a common root context (services, datasources etc). It also gives a good practice roadmap for creating layered contexts, i.e. prevent your service beans to have dependencies on your mvc layer.

Unless you have more than one configuration files, you should assign an empty value to the contextConfigLocation of your servlet configuration as :

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

Be careful. Do not omit the parameter. Spring will infer some default configuration file name based on your servlet and will complain if it does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment pointed me to the right direction. I couldn't fix the problem by what you suggest above as this would break mappings in my controllers so instead I created two separate configuration files passing one to the DispatcherServlet.

Answer (score 0):

GenericFilterBean is not in an application context. I would expect java.lang.InstantiationException in the code above. You can get your bean via the filter's **ServletContext**. Any other instantiation trick will cause map duplication.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "GenericFilter is not in an application context"? I do define MyFilter in my application context and I am not getting any instantiation exceptions...

Comment: So, it means you have two different contexts. That is why you have two instances. In your code Service and Controller are annotated but filter is not. And by idea of **GenericFilter** it should not be in application context.

Comment: So why/how are two contexts are created? I did not annotate the filter because I define it in my app-config (see above edit). I had to define it in the application context since it is referenced by other elements there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there is only one instance of MyService class created? The simplest way to check this is to provide default constructor implementation and print some text in it. Please check this and let me know, because I have some suspicions.

If this is true, and there are two instances of MyService class, there is possibility that when you put some data to map, you use *instance A of MyService* and when you get data from the map you use *instance B of MyService*... I will wait for your response to continue/stop this thinking.

Comment: That was my first thought but as I mentioned in the question above the same instance of MyService gets injected. So that's not the source of the problem.